# Error in Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm create validation using javascript to identity number with the following format : xxx-xxxx (3 digit number - 4 digit number).

My script is :

```
var idpattern = /^([0-9]{3})\-([0-9]{4})$/;
var id = $('#id').val();
if (idpattern.test(id) == false){
    window.alert('Your format is not valid');
    return false;
}
```

But when i test typing, for example: 123-4567. The site responded false. It said that my input is not valid. I've just tested using ([Rubular](http://rubular.com), the pattern is ok. What's wrong with this script?

Comment: `/^([0-9]{3})\-([0-9]{4})$/.test("123-4567")` logs true, it's not the pattern. What's `id`?

Comment: to piggyback on @BenjaminGruenbaum's comment, you might `console.log(id)` to see if that is what you expect it to be (a string containing the value "123-4567")

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum = it's user defined id.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine for that kind of input - see demo: http://codepen.io/rsp/pen/qtywe - Are you sure that you are getting value from the right DOM element?

Comment: Sorry all.... It's my own mistake. I create 2 input object with same id. So, it may confuse the jQuery response.

Comment: But.... Thanks for all your suggestions....